# Knockout content editable custom binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, contenteditable

Why in this example http://jsfiddle.net/JksKx/8/ div lost cursor when i write text? How to fix such behavior?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The keyup event is firing and writing to your viewmodel, which then triggers the update function of the custom binding.  This is writing the innerHTML back to the element, which is causing you to lose focus.

An easy fix is to check in the update function if the element.innerHTML already is the same as the value that you want to set it to.

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/JksKx/9/

```
ko.bindingHandlers.htmlValue = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "keydown", function() {
            var modelValue = valueAccessor();
            var elementValue = element.innerHTML;
            if (ko.isWriteableObservable(modelValue)) {
                modelValue(elementValue);
            }
            else { //handle non-observable one-way binding
                var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
                if (allBindings['_ko_property_writers'] && allBindings['_ko_property_writers'].htmlValue) allBindings['_ko_property_writers'].htmlValue(elementValue);
            }
        }
                                     )
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) || "";
        if (element.innerHTML !== value) {
            element.innerHTML = value;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Two things i noticed on this contenteditable binding: 1. Make sure that data-bind is not inside element with contenteditable attribute. Element with contenteditable will not fire key event. 2. If user right click on element and paste text, this will not update value. click event also should be assigned. Also if using buttons like "bold" click event should be bound to body or something like that.

Comment: Using focus seems to work for "bold" click events and other similar.

ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "focus", updateHandler);

Answer (score 3):

might want to change keydown to keyup, but other than that works really well =)

```
ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "keyup", function() {
```