# knockout contentEditable binding

Tags: knockout.js

I've written a custom binding handler that toggles whether or not an element is contentEditable.  I also want any html bindings to update when the element's contents are edited, so it listens for input events and updates the html bindings if available.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.contentEditable = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        element.contentEditable = value;

        var $element = $(element);

        if (value) {
            var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
            var htmlBinding = allBindings.html;

            if (ko.isWriteableObservable(htmlBinding)) {
                $element.on("input", function (event) {
                    htmlBinding(element.innerHTML);
                });
            }
        } else {
            $element.off("input");
        }
    }
};
```

However, here is the problem:

- The user types something into the element
- An input event fires
- The html binding is updated
- The element's innerHTML is updated
- The cursor position in the element goes back to the beginning

A jsfiddle says a thousand words... http://jsfiddle.net/93eEr/1/

I'm a bit stumped as to how exactly to handle this.

Comment: You need to wrap the html value in a computed, that only updates the html binding if you are not editing. Also it should notify of mutation when you stop editing

Comment: Quick and dirty is to only update when blur http://jsfiddle.net/93eEr/2/

Comment: A nicer version would be to write a new binding handler, for lack of a better name, let's call it `htmlLazy`, which updates the DOM elements it is bound to only when they are not currently `contentEditable`.

Comment: have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7904779/168097)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.htmlLazy = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        
        if (!element.isContentEditable) {
            element.innerHTML = value;
        }
    }
};
ko.bindingHandlers.contentEditable = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()),
            htmlLazy = allBindingsAccessor().htmlLazy;
        
        $(element).on("input", function () {
            if (this.isContentEditable && ko.isWriteableObservable(htmlLazy)) {
                htmlLazy(this.innerHTML);
            }
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        
        element.contentEditable = value;
        
        if (!element.isContentEditable) {
            $(element).trigger("input");
        }
    }
};

var viewModel = {
    editable: ko.observable(false),
    content: ko.observable("<i>This</i> is the initial content!")
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<label>Editable: <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: editable"/></label>
<hr>
<div data-bind="contentEditable: editable, htmlLazy: content"></div>
<hr>
<pre data-bind="text: content"></pre>
```

do the trick with minimal change. See http://jsfiddle.net/93eEr/3/

You could call the binding handler `htmlEditable`, maybe that's better than calling it "lazy". Up to you.

Note that the "input" event does not really need to be unbound every time. It won't fire anyway when the element is not contenteditable.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  The reason I was unbinding the input event was because I wanted to bind on update, not init.  In my situation there will be hundreds of these editable sections on a page but only one or two will probably be edited on any given page view.  I wanted to avoid the overhead of attaching all the events during the init.

Comment: I see. You can use event delegation in that case - just bind the `input` event handler to the container and use `ko.contextFor(this)` to obtain the binding context (also [see](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html), but note that the documentation refers to the now obsolete `.live` and `.delegate` functions, which have been superseded by `.on()`).

Comment: +1 This is really useful. NB if you change the binding in the `contentEditable` handler to the following, it works in IE as well: `$(element).on("input blur keyup paste copy cut mouseup", function () {` [etc]

Comment: @JcFx Thanks for the heads-up. You're free to suggest the appropriate edit!

Comment: This doesn't work properly if you decide to set `contentEditable='true'` on the DOM. To handle this I added: `element.innerHTML = htmlLazy();` to the contentEditable init handler.

Answer (score 4):

@Tomalak's answer is perfect, hence my upvote.

But for those arriving here, like myself:

- looking for a one-and-done custom binding
- that assumes the content is **always** editable
- is ok with `value:`-esque updates (ie: on blur)

I suggest the following:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.contentEditable = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();

        function onBlur(){
            if (ko.isWriteableObservable(value)) {
                value(this.innerHTML);
            }
        };                

        element.innerHTML = value(); //set initial value
        element.contentEditable = true; //mark contentEditable true
        element.addEventListener('blur', onBlur); //add blur listener
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In previous I have problem with bdo that resolve it by this code.
also this code is usable for other contentEditable.
so I suggest the following:

```
 ko.bindingHandlers.bdoValue =
 ko.bindingHandlers.contentEditable = {
      'init': function(element, valueAccessor) {
          var updateHandler = function() {
              var modelValue = valueAccessor(),
                  elementValue = element.innerHTML;
              modelValue(elementValue);
          };
          ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "keyup", updateHandler);
          ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "input", updateHandler);
      },
      'update': function(elem, valueAccessor) {
          var value = ko.utils.unwrap(valueAccessor())||"";
          var current = elem.innerHTML;
          if (value !== current) {
              elem.innerHTML = value;    
          }
      }
   };
```