# Knockout: automatic push for an array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, binding

I have a div bound to an observable array like so:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: currentSelected().Tags " contenteditable="true">
    <span data-bind="text:$data"></span>
</div>
```

I made the div's content editable so that any changes (user input) get reflected in the Tags array, but that isn't working as I assumed. There seems to be no automatic push for observable arrays. My question is, how do I get new values inside the Tags array using binding?

Here is how I am setting currentSelected:

```
var newBlogEntry = new NewBlogEntry();
var newBlogEntryObservable = new NewBlogEntryObservable(newBlogEntry);
self.currentSelected(newBlogEntryObservable);
```

The function for NewBlogEntry is as follows:

```
function NewBlogEntry()
{
    return { "Id": 0, "Title": "Title", "Description": "Description", "Tags": [] };
}
```

Comment: At least related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19370098/knockout-contenteditable-binding You certainly can't have bindings *within* the contenteditable element, you'll have to just make the element editable and then map back to `Tags` when it is changed...

Comment: Referring to the related post answer, what would be the content in my case? Would it be currentSelected().Tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by adding an extra input field:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="new tag" data-bind="value:newTag, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', enterkey: addNewTag" id="addTag" />
```

The binding for the enter key is as follows:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.enterkey = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel) {
        var callback = valueAccessor();
        $(element).keypress(function (event) {
        var keyCode = (event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode);
        if (keyCode === 13) {
            callback.call(viewModel);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
    }
};
```

And this is the observable for the newTag:

```
self.newTag = ko.observable();
self.addNewTag = function () {
    if (self.newTag() == '')
        alert("Enter something in input field");
    else {
        var tag = self.newTag();
        self.currentSelected().Tags.push(tag);
        $("#addTag").val("");
    }
}
```