# knockout contentditable binding with array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I am trying to create a custom binding to edit content with HTML5 on a table following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19370098/knockout-contenteditable-binding?newreg=43e25a4590eb4fb7ba8da72c59e96557) example and I can't get it to work with an observableArray().

The table is being show in the view with foreach data-bindig like this:

```
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: customers">
            <tr data-bind="attr: {id: $index}">
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                    <span class="label label-primary" data-bind="html: Id"></span>
                </td>
                <td data-bind="html: Name, attr: {id: 'Nome'}, contentEditable: true"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

The view model is this:

function ViewModel() {

```
        var self = this;

        self.data = '@jsonList';
        self.customers = ko.observableArray(JSON.parse(self.data));
        self.editable = ko.observable(false);

        for (i = 0; i < self.customers().length; i++) {

            self.customers()[i]['Details'] = '/Anagrafica/Details/' + self.customers()[i]['Id'];

            self.customers()[i]['Delete'] = '/Anagrafica/Delete/' + self.customers()[i]['Id'];

        };

        ko.bindingHandlers.htmlEdit= {

            update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
            }
        };

        ko.bindingHandlers.contentEditable = {

            init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
                var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()),
                    htmlEdit= allBindingsAccessor().htmlEdit;

                $(element).on("input", function () {
                    if (ko.isWriteableObservable(htmlEdit)) {
                        htmlEdit(this.innerHTML);
                    }
                });
            },

            update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
                element.contentEditable = value;
                $(element).trigger("input");
            }

        };
    };


    var viewModel = new ViewModel();

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

At the moment I am confused on the code itself, because I don't understand how to set it to point to the elements on the array.

Note: The array is populated, I have no problems in show the content.

Edit: here I add the JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wxn34p45/ for a better read of the code

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you had a spelling mistake Name instead of name:

```
<td data-bind="html: name, attr: {id: 'Nome'}, contentEditable: true"></td>
```

Also customers was not an observableArray (in your fiddle at least):

```
self.customers = ko.observableArray([{"Id":1111,"name":" [Malena]"},{"Id":2222,"name":" [Maria]"},{"Id":3333,"name":" [Merio]"},{"Id":4444,"name":" [Milena]"}]);
```

I have updated the fiddle (also got it running with knockout, and I have displayed a copy of the ViewModel to help with debugging), the content is now editable.

```
<h4>View Model</h4>
  <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
```

Is this now giving the desired effect?

https://jsfiddle.net/asindlemouat/wxn34p45/1/

**EDIT**

With the further information provided I have managed to make this editable, I have removed the editable from the customers array and used the one in the ViewModel.

As it is looping through the customers array you need to call the editable observable in the ViewModel using $parent.editable.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: customers">
  <tr data-bind="attr: {id: $index}">
    <td style="text-align: center;">
      <span class="label label-primary" data-bind="html: Id"></span>
    </td>
    <td data-bind="html: name, attr: {id: 'Nome'}, contentEditable: $parent.editable"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/asindlemouat/wxn34p45/8/

Comment: Thanks for you intrest and for the edit on my Fiddle (I am terrible at use it), but no: it still don't get the modifications. The final aim is to use it to change the original model with an Ajax call ^^" But I know already how to do that call

Comment: I mean, the content should be editable with "contentEditable: editable" so that the custom handler will change the parameter that's in the observable array

Comment: Ok, what triggers the the change between editable and not editable? The example from the accepted answer in the link you provided to the other SO post they are using a checkbox to change the value of `self.editable`.

Comment: there's a button that I didn't write, sorry: howeven modified it now, with the checkbox and added "editable" to the VM "customers", but now the editable does not work lol

Comment: Do you have a link to the updated fiddle then I might be able to see what wrong?

Comment: Updated my answer, hope this gives you what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but I decided to drop it as the documentation isn't really helpful and to adopt AngularJs instead (1.6 version) that suits all my needs.